# ASP.NET Web API 2 - State & Static Scope

Tags: asp.net-web-api, state, static-variables

I am a relatively inexperienced programmer.

I have managed to build a web api which uses basic authentication as per the following: 
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter which is working very nicely (forced over ssl obviously). Inside the OnAuthorizeUser i check the un/pw against an mssql database, via a call to an internal class called "DB" where all my database interaction occurs.

So all Controller methods are filtered by the Basic Authentication ("decorated" at the Controller level) however, access to certain Controller Methods also needs to be limited depending on the user - so there is a need to understand the user permissions. Based on my limited former ASP.NET experience I think I would have stored the relevant user details in a Session (or possibly cache) however I have so far steered clear of this based on wanting to stick to the concept of having a RESTful application etc

Rightly or wrongly, in playing around I realised I could use a private static (instance?) of my User class inside my internal DB class and populate it at the time of initial authorisation. I also added a public method (public User getThisUser()) to return the private User. From within my Controller methods I create an instance of DB and am able to check the values etc.

I was very worried that I would have issues with the "scope" of this "static" User, so to test, I created a Controller method to simply return the User information from DB.getThisUser(). In doing so I have found that I can log in as multiple different users (using different browsers concurrently for example) and each one consistently returns the correct user information (as logged in).

I'm still not entirely convinced this is "safe" however reading through the details of implementing something like ASP.NET Identity as a possible alternative makes my head spin and really seems like massive overkill in this case - I'm not using Entity Framework and after much searching I could not find a single example of NOT using an ORM (I need a solution to work with an existing DB).

Is this destined to fail? Do I go back to considering session or cache? Something else? I would really appreciate any feedback / advice on this from all of you who are more experienced than me. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

i think you're getting a bit confused.

an API is supposed to be stateless, meaning no session. Yes, you have a controller which translates into an endpoint.

You can hit an endpoint with all the information required to satisfy the request and this is it. Don't think of an API as an actual application where all requests are linked somehow. Instead, think of it at an application where each request is separate and can come from anywhere and any user.

How does the application know which user sent a request? Well, it doesn't unless you pass that information in.

You don't fire a request saying GetMeUserDetails. The api has no idea what you want. Instead you would say GetMeUserDetails for userId 12345. Now, since your request contains all the information required to satisfy the request, the API can now give you what you expect.

If some calls require authentication, you might use some sort of tokens to identify the user, but again, the information is passed in via the token.

You probably realize what *static* means and how it works. you are not going to see problems until you try to send two or more requests at the same time and then you'll realize that the first call now contains the details of the second request because well, static ...

Comment: I may well be confused :). Are you saying the request should contain the user info? All methods are behind the auth filt, so it seemed logical to use that info. The api "knows" who the user is since they only log in once. Perhaps the key is in your comment "use some sort of token"?  Where i definitely AM confused, is how I can replicate two or more requests at the same time and get confused results. Logging in to 2 different browsers as two different users,calling the same methods is working fine. appreciate the reply but I think I need a little more.

Comment: after more thought. you are right, I could have the userkey included in the calls.I have a couple of extra flags that restrict post but allow get for example. should this then happen at the db rather than the controller? seemed like unnecessary trips to the db at the time.